# Word/phrase for "things that are too much for us to bear"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

> I have a theory. We created laughter to protect us from **things
>   that are too much for us to bear.**

I'm sure there's a word or a shorter phrase for the **bolded** part.

Comment: Unbearable things.

Comment: Large elephants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We created laughter to protect us from **the unbearable.**

Answer (score 1):

> **ONEROUS** *adjective*:
>
> **1**:  involving, imposing, or constituting a burden :  troublesome <*an onerous task*>
>
> **2**:  having legal obligations that outweigh the advantages <*an onerous contract*>
>
> — oner·ous·ly *adverb*
>
> — oner·ous·ness *noun*

**Traumatic** *adjective*: emotionally disturbing or distressing.

**Trauma** *noun*: a very difficult or unpleasant experience that causes someone to have mental or emotional problems usually for a long time

From: [**Merriam-Webster online**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/onerous)

Answer (score 0):

a bit much, insufferable, intolerable, enough already, last straw